# slack api rtm direct message

Tags: websocket, slack-api

I'm using a node package: slack-client to interact with the api at slack.  Now with or without using slack-client how do I send a direct message from my bot to a user I want to specify?  Here's what  have so far with  a plain socket connection:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
,ws2 = new WebSocket(myURL); //from rtm start
 ws2.on('open', function() {
    ws2.send({
    "id": 333,
    "type": "message",
    "channel": "@user1", //User I want to send to
    "text": "HEY!!!!"
    });
});
ws2.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
});
```

I was hoping that message would go directly to me from the bot but nothing. I get a reply of type hello though? The send details above I got on another post about this but it doesn't work for me. The message Id was one I created.

Comment: I got an email from the slack support which should provide a solution to this. Will add an answer later this evening if it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok so when calling the rtm.start via the web api, you would get a list of DM's that would be open for various users otherwise you can easily just open an im with im.open. I'm using the node package slack-client as mentioned in my question so you can do this:

```
     //name of user your bot wants to send a msg to.
     var userTest = slack.getUserByName('user1');
     slack.openDM(userTest.id, function(res)
     {
         TestMsg(res.channel.id, 'some other msg');//test function I'm using
     });
```

Next is the TestMsg function:

```
function TestMsg(userChannelId, msg)
{
  request.post({url:     'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage',
                form:    { token: "xxxx-yourbot-token",channel: userChannelId,text: msg ,username: "yourBotNamehere", as_user: false}
              }, function(error, response, body){
                console.log(response.body);
               });
}
```

I couldn't get it to work yet using the websockets send method but I suppose the api of postMessage will do for now as you can post richly formatted messages with postMessage. Hope this helps someone